# How can I add value to my Octopus card directly from my debit/credit card in Hong Kong?

Tags: trains, public-transport, payment-cards, hong-kong

How can I add value to my Octopus card directly from my debit/credit card in Hong Kong?

The couple of "Add Value Machine" I have seen in the MTR and HKG airport only accepts cash:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer - You can't.  Cash only! This is true not only at the Add Value Machines, but also at the service desk and all other locations.

Longer Answer - It is actually possible to top-up an Octopus card using a credit card, but it can only be done using the "[Automatic Add Value Service](http://www.octopus.com.hk/en/consumer/octopus-cards/aavs/index.html)" ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190108005947/https://www.octopus.com.hk/en/consumer/octopus-cards/aavs/index.html)), which is only available for customers of specific Hong Kong banks.  Presuming that you are not a HK/Chinese resident, then this option is not available to you, so we're back to the Simple answer of "You Can't"

Comment: For interest, it used to be possible in the last decade via EPS (again, local cards only), but they discontinued this payment option after a massive bug, where money is deducted from your bank account but not added to the Octopus card, is discovered.

Comment: @B.Liu I always thought the discontinuation was ultimately some sort of business decision, to promote AAVS or whatever. One would think 10 years would be long enough to fix a service that many other systems in the world have.

Comment: @user71659 One would hope so right... Though (after some archive digging) it seems fixing the service was [not even considered back then](https://web.archive.org/web/20080924012450/http://www.rthk.org.hk/rthk/news/expressnews/20071221/news_20071221_55_455661.htm).